# Meteor: How to import a website with pages, images, links, etc

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor. I have a website that I want to convert into meteor. Do I have to set up a router, and change all of the links? Or can I use the existing href links that navigate between the html pages? Will images be a problem? Will the css and javascript in each of the page headers work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Routes you should define it using the meteor package [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router), [here is common tutorial](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial)

so if you have something like `myUrl/about`.

you should do something in meteor like this.

```
Router.route('about',function(){
  this.render('about') //and you should have a <template name="about></template>
})
```

About images, you should put images under the /public directory, check more on the official meteor docs [structuringmyapp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

If you web use jquery plugins you should use a [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) function

```
Template.example.rendered(function(){
  //initialize jquery plugins
})
```

All this because like you say on the question, you have Routes, if you don't have routes.

If you want to test it on a live editor you can use [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/).

I recommend you to read the [discoverMeteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com) book or install the [2 example from meteor](https://www.meteor.com/try/12), also the [Meteor tutorials Begginers](http://meteortips.com/book/) its a good option here

Answer (score -1):

Add [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) to route your website.

```
// Router Example
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'Layout' //Layout is a template for your website
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'}); // Index is an another template
});
```

Layout template should have `{{> yield}}` tag

```
<template name="Layout">
// Include header in separate template
 {{> yield}}
// Include footed in separate template
</template>

<template name="index">
 <!-- Page content -->
</template>
```

to execute JQuery ready function by

```
Template.Layout.onRendered({
   //JQuery content HERE
});
```

Hope this will enough for simple website